# Node js loop of promises to observable

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, rxjs, observable

I have a method that makes a number of async queries to DB to retrieve large amount of data. For simplicity, lets say that each query returns an array of integers. I want to turn this method to observable and output numbers one by one. This part is working fine.

The problem starts with 'take' operator - I would like to stop DB requests if nobody is listening to the result anyway. And my problem is that the 'scroll' function wouldn't stop executing until it will hit its stopping condition, even if 'largeQueryPromise' doesn't listen to it anymore due to take(10) operator.

Is there any possibility to stop the execution of observable, when the subscriber unsubsribes due to various reasons?

```
let ind = 0;
function dbRequest(): Promise<number[]> {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve([ind++, ind++]));
}

async function largeQuery(index: number) {
    let res = await dbRequest();
    return new Observable(observer => scroll(observer, res, index));
}

function scroll(observer: Subscriber<number>, res: number[], index: number) {
    if (Math.round(Math.random() * 5) === 0) {
        console.log(`completed sequence ${index}`);
        observer.complete();
        return;
    }

    res.forEach(value => observer.next(value));
    dbRequest().then(arr => scroll(observer, arr, index));
}

async function largeQueryPromise(index: number) {
    console.log(`started sequence ${index}`);
    const obs = await largeQuery(index);
    obs.pipe(take(10)).subscribe(
        undefined, 
        console.error, 
        () => {
            console.log(`stopped to listen for sequence ${index}`);
            largeQueryPromise(++index).then();
        });
}

largeQueryPromise(0).then();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observer has a parameter "closed" that indicates whether that subscriber has unsubscribed. Knowing this the solution is trivial:

```js
function scroll(observer: Subscriber<number>, res: number[], index: number) {
    if (Math.round(Math.random() * 5) === 0) {
        console.log(`completed sequence ${index}`);
        observer.complete();
        return;
    }

    for(let i=0; i<res.length && !observer.closed; i++)
        observer.next(res[i]);

    if(!observer.closed)
        dbRequest().then(arr => scroll(observer, arr, index));
}
```

Edit: Note that technically you don't need the check in the for loop - all .next will be a noop.

Comment: Thank you, that solves my issue. Though I was expecting something like event, so I can react on it.

Comment: If you return a function inside the observable constructor, that function will get called when you need to clean up (e.g. `new Observable(obs => { obs.next(1); return () => /* .. cleanup .. */; })`). Note that as it's a returned function you still need to check for observer.closed in the synchronous block above.

Answer (score 1):

Your largeQuery can be done with operators only. Use `expand` to recursively call `dbRequest()` when the previous request emitted. End this recursion by returning `EMPTY`. Use `concatAll` to spread the incoming arrays emits.

```ts
function largeQuery(index: number): Observable<number> {
  console.log("largeQuery2 for", index);
  return from(dbRequest()).pipe(
    expand(res => {
      if (Math.round(Math.random() * 5) === 0) {
        console.log(`completed sequence ${index}`);
        return EMPTY;
      }
      // The observable returned here gets subscribed to before the 'take' operator
      // below ends the subscription. To prevent an additional call of 'dbRequest'
      // at the end, the observable returned here has to be asynchronous. 
      // That's why 'timer' is used. 
      // If this doesn't turn out to be an issue for you, the line below could be 
      // replace with 'return defer(() => dbRequest())' or even 'return from(dbRequest())'
      return timer(0).pipe(switchMap(() => dbRequest()));
    }),
    concatAll()
  );
}

function recursiveLargeQuery(index: number) {
  console.log(`started sequence ${index}`);
  largeQuery(index).pipe(
    take(10),
  ).subscribe(
    v => console.log(v), 
    console.error, 
    () => {
      console.log(`stopped to listen for sequence ${index}`);
      if (index < 2) { // end the recursion at some point
        recursiveLargeQuery(++index);
      }
    });
}

recursiveLargeQuery(0)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ihxkax?file=index.ts